# Android Google Direction API, How To Ignore One Way Street

Tags: android, google-directions-api

How to make a Google Direction API url that ignores one way street restriction and only go through national streets (big streets)? What parameters I should add?

Here's my current code:

```
private String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString(destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    urlString.append("&key=my_key");
    return urlString.toString();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GOOGLE direction API **avaid** parameter supports the following arguments:

**tolls** indicates that the calculated route should avoid toll roads/bridges.

**highways** indicates that the calculated route should avoid highways.

**ferries** indicates that the calculated route should avoid ferries.

**indoor** indicates that the calculated route should avoid indoor steps for

**walking** and transit directions.

Only requests that include an API key or a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID will receive indoor steps by default.
For more information see Route Restrictions below [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Restrictions)
**Google Direction API, does not provides  Ignore One Way Street features** .

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about how to ignore one way street restriction. So the result will go through against it, not to avoid anything.